# Canvas: JavaScript Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The site is: http://www.clubloc.com/

And it works in firefox but not in google chrome.  Internet explorer also has problems but thats pretty much a given when using HTML5 Canvas.

Anyways I'm trying to figure out why it throws the error:
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

When the arrays clearly have all those elements, I even logged their size and it says 100.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any code will also be very much appreciated.

Comment: It happens because circlesR values can become negative at some point. The radius of a circle cannot be negative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zneak has the answer right, I just fixed it.

I wasn't doing the radial boundary testing early enough...
Canvas doesn't like it if you have a negative radius :-).

Thanks zneak!